# How to get the height of an dynamically created textarea AS3? Flash Builder 4.6

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flex4

I'm trying to get the width and height of an textarea, but this sounds impossible. I'm Using Flash Builder 4.6

I have a button that dynamically creates a textarea, and add some text to it. It's height is defined automatically according to the number of characters and lines the text added have.

So, after this I need to get it's height in pixels.

textArea.height doesn't return height right after it's creating creation.

---

It is a few weird because I can never retrieve the height of the last created textarea, but I can retrieve the height of previously textarea, that were stored on an array.

thanks in advance, for your help.

Comment: Well provide some code. What you are saying is not true - getting height should be synchronous operation!

Answer (score 0):

The reason your text area does not have its `height` set when you *create* it is that it has not been laid out yet. One way that you can obtain its dimensions is if you listen on its `resize` event.